# How to create dynamic material ui table in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React to display client information. Currently I have hardcoded the table header and table cell's values. My indented result is

[image]

I have an array like ClientAddress =[{addressLine1Desc : "1 Apple Park Way", addressLine2Desc: null, ....}]. I want the first two be in a row and next two items are in second row and so on...

I have harcoded like this

```
<Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography variant="h5" component="div" className="cardTitle">
                <MailOutlineIcon />&nbsp;Primary Address

              </Typography>
              
              <TableContainer component={Paper} sx={{ width: 400, margin: 'auto', display: 'Block', boxShadow: 'none' }}>
                <Table sx={{ minWidth: 400 }} aria-label="customized table">
                  <TableBody>
                    
                    <TableRow className='tableRow'>
                    
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" className="tableCell">
                        <span className="cellHeader">Address Line1</span><br />{clientAddressDetails.length ? <span className='cellValue'>{clientAddressDetails[0].addressLine1Desc}</span> : <span className='cellValue'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" className="tableCell">
                        <span className="cellHeader">Address Line2</span><br />{clientAddressDetails.length ? <span className='cellValue'>{clientAddressDetails[0].addressLine2Desc}</span> : <span className='cellValue'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow className='tableRow'>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" className="tableCell">
                        <span className="cellHeader">Address Line3</span><br />{clientAddressDetails.length ? <span className='cellValue'>{clientAddressDetails[0].addressLine3Desc}</span> : <span className='cellValue'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" className="tableCell">
                        <span className="cellHeader">Address Line4</span><br />{clientAddressDetails.length ? <span className='cellValue'>{clientAddressDetails[0].addressLine4Desc}</span> : <span className='cellValue'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow className='tableRow'>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" className="tableCell">
                        <span className="cellHeader">Country Code</span><br />{clientAddressDetails.length ? <span className='cellValue'>{clientAddressDetails[0].countryCode}</span> : <span className='cellValue'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" className="tableCell">
                        <span className="cellHeader">Country Name</span><br />{clientAddressDetails.length ? <span className='cellValue'>{clientAddressDetails[0].countryCode}</span> : <span className='cellValue'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow className='tableRow'>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" className="tableCell">
                        <span className="cellHeader">CityName</span><br />{clientAddressDetails.length ? <span className='cellValue'>{clientAddressDetails[0].cityName}</span> : <span className='cellValue'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row" className="tableCell">
                        <span className="cellHeader">PostalCode</span><br />{clientAddressDetails.length ? <span className='cellValue'>{clientAddressDetails[0].postalCode}</span> : <span className='cellValue'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  </TableBody>
                </Table>
              </TableContainer>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
```

I want to display like the above image dynamically instead of having repeated code. I need to do this for displaying other information in this format

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code for map function

```
<Grid container rowSpacing={1} columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }}>
      {clientAddressDetails.length>0 && Object.keys(clientAddressDetails[0]).map(key=>(
    
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Item>
     <span className="cellHeader">Address Line1</span><br />
     {clientAddressDetails[0][key] && <span className='cellValue'>{clientAddressDetails[0][key]}</span>}
            
    </Item>
      </Grid>           
     ))}         
    </Grid>
```

Here is the doc [link](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/).

Loop through the above DOM with help for your array data.

Comment: My only intention is to not write repetitive code ( Table row and table cell) . If I loop thru this as you said, it will create so many cards.. I mean as long as the looping goes

Comment: So what do you want ?

Comment: Picture this, I have ten values in clientAddressDetails. I need to display first two values as two columns in a single row. Then next two should be in a two columns in the next row. So everything must be dynamic. Please refer the pic above

Comment: what is your current data display?

Comment: Please refer the picture above. After hardcoding it's displayed like that. Instead of hardcoding, I need to display dynamically

Comment: are you sure, if data change might add n number of field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251993/discussion-between-sushildlh-and-lakshmi).